# jQuery - finding the exact target of a click (Code works in Chrome but not Firefox)

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, crash, target

I have an entire TD set up to be clickable to minimize and maximize it. However, I want to make it so that if a certain part of the TD is clicked, it doesn't min/max it, but executes some other code. After reading around this site and google I figured out I would need to find the event's target. I took that code from another question on stackoverflow and it works perfectly in Chrome, but the JS crashes in Firefox.

Here is where it crashes:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.clickable').live('click', function()
    {
        alert('click');
        //Figuring out where a user clicked
        var targ;
        var e;
        if (!e) 
            e = window.event;
        if (e.target) 
            targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) 
            targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;

        alert('after');
        });
return false;
});
```

In both cases, the alert 'click' is displayed, but only in Chrome is 'after' displayed. Any help?

Comment: Side note, as of jQuery 1.7, the correct syntax is `$(document).on('click', '.clickable', functino(){});` instead of the live call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
var e;
if (!e) 
    e = window.event;
```

and add the event `e` as function parameter:

```
$('.clickable').live('click', function(e)
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/StxAJ/).

Answer (score 1):

With nested click handlers you can stop the event bubbling up like so,

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(){
    //do stuff
});

 $('#mytable').on('click', '.clickable-child', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //do child stuff
});
```

The stop propagation will not allow the first event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vHgVa/